# Maven: Copy some dependencies into a libraries directory and merge others into the output JAR

Tags: java, maven

I have a project with `maven` dependencies and I want to instruct `maven` to copy some dependencies into a `libraries` directory and make it merge others directly into the output `JAR`.

So far I used the `maven-dependency-plugin` to copy all dependencies into a `libraries` directory:

```
<properties>
    <libraries.directory>libraries</libraries.directory>
</properties>

<!-- ... -->

<!-- Copy JAR libraries to target folder -->
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.1.1</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${libraries.directory}</outputDirectory>
            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

This works. However, now I want to exclude a specific `groupdId` and instead merge that dependency into the output `JAR` like described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42513862/3764804) answer.

I can successfully exclude the `groupId` with `excludeGroupIds` but adding a second `execution` block with an `includeGroupIds` tag causes the dependency to be copied into a `target/dependency` subdirectory which is not what I want.

I furthermore use the `maven-jar-plugin` to build my `JAR` and reference the `libraries` directory on the `classpath`:

```
<!-- Generate Target JAR -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            !-- Drop the META-INF/maven folder -->
            <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>${libraries.directory}</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>ApplicationClient</mainClass>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Built-By>Me</Built-By>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Maybe the dependency inclusion in the `JAR` has to be configured for the `maven-jar-plugin` instead, how can that be done?

Comment: You are trying to create a executable jar file which should be done by using maven-shade-plugin or via maven-assembly-plugin...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using the `maven-dependency-plugin`...

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${libraries.directory}</outputDirectory>
                <!-- Excluded in the libraries directory -->
                <excludeGroupIds>com.mycompany, com.mysecondcompany</excludeGroupIds>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and `maven-shade-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <artifactSet>
                <!-- Included in the fat JAR -->
                <includes>
                    <include>com.mycompany:*:jar:</include>
                    <include>com.mysecondcompany:*:jar:</include>
                </includes>
            </artifactSet>

            <transformers>
                <transformer
                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                </transformer>
            </transformers>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Irrelevant tags have been removed for clarity.